# Android Resouce by ID / Change image onClick / no change of imageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-xml, android-drawable

I have a problem with my imageview not changing after picking an image from an array (xml resource), but falling back into the default value.

Content of my MeasurementActivity.java

```
public class MeasurementActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_measurement);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        final ImageView imageViewMeasurement = (ImageView) findViewById(measurement_image_view);

        //Button here to change the image in the imageView "imageViewMeasurement"
        Button button_like = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_like);
        button_like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d("MYAPP", "Like-Button clicked");

                /*imageViewMeasurement.setImageResource(R.drawable.p13);*/

                TypedArray images = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.images_primes);
                int chosenImageNumber = (int) (Math.random() * images.length());

                // setImageResource to the random chosenImageNumber
                imageViewMeasurement.setImageResource(images.getResourceId(chosenImageNumber, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                images.recycle();

                // Confirmation if the random generator picked a Number from the array
                String chosenImageNumberTest = String.valueOf(chosenImageNumber);
                Log.d("MYAPP Choice Number", chosenImageNumberTest);
            }

        });

    }    
}
```

Content of my array_images_measurement.xml:

```
<resources>
    <array name="images_primes">
            <item>"@drawable/p1"</item>
            <item>"@drawable/p15"</item>
            <item>"@drawable/p20"</item>
            <item>"@drawable/p25"</item>
            <item>"@drawable/p30"</item>
            <item>"@drawable/p35"</item>
            <item>"@drawable/p40"</item>
            <item>"@drawable/p45"</item>
            <item>"@drawable/p50"</item>
            <item>"@drawable/p55"</item>
            <item>"@drawable/p60"</item>
            <item>"@drawable/p65"</item>
    </array>
    <array name="images_target">
            <item>"@drawable/t1"</item>
            <item>"@drawable/t5"</item>
            <item>"@drawable/t10"</item>
            <item>"@drawable/t15"</item>
            <item>"@drawable/t20"</item>
    </array>
```

Content of my activity_measurement.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <ImageView 
                   android:id="@+id/measurement_image_view" 
                   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                   android:layout_height="400dp" 
                   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
                   android:text="Left" 
                   android:src="@drawable/starttest" 
                   android:padding="10dp" />
        <Button 
                android:text="@string/button_like" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/button_like" 
                android:layout_marginBottom="26dp" 
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Expected behaviour:

- I click on the button id: "button_like", the image "starttest" (as declared in activity_measurement.xml) changes to a randomly picked image from the array "images_primes" (11 imtems to choose).

Actual happening:

- I click on the button id: "button_like", the image "starttest" changes to the default color ("R.color.colorPrimaryDark").
- The log-output seems ok, it every time I use the button it shows an other (random) number
- Changing the command just to change the image without picking it from a xml resource (imageViewMeasurement.setImageResource(R.drawable.p13)); works without any problems

Question: Why do the images not show up (or the imageview doesn't refresh (?))?

Best
tigercode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining your array wrong. and because your app can't find the correct item it goes back to the default image. a drawable is a id and an ID is an integer (you have strings) try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <array name="random_imgs">
        <item>@drawable/tests1</item>
        <item>@drawable/tests2</item>
        <item>@drawable/tests3</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

And for retreiving the drawable

```
TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.random_imgs);

Random r = new Random();
int i = random.nextInt(imgs.size() -1);

// get resource ID by index
imgs.getResourceId(i, R.color.colorPrimaryDark)

// or set you ImageView's resource to the id
mImgView1.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(i, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

// recycle the array
imgs.recycle();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - but the "interger-array" expects an integer (value) as shown here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#IntegerArray

-> Android Studio colores the @drawable-imports red with: "Cannot resolve symbol "@drawable/p20"

Comment: Ow woops yes indeed I wrote the wrong array, it is confusing because the @drawables are indeed integers, but this should work

Comment: I'm a bit confused now, hope I don't read something wrong - but as far as I see that's exactly the solution I came up with in the first post, which doesn't work so far. Or have I overseen the difference, than sorry in advance.

Comment: you have added place " around your drawables, and indeed like @yotam hadas said, you need to add your random different. I would do it like in my sollution

Comment: OMG. " makes it fail. Thanks so much for your patience!

Comment: thats why I said you have an array of strings ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
                int chosenImageNumber = (int) (Math.random() * images.length());
```

I think the above line is the problem.
You should use:

```
Match.random(images.length(-1));
```