# Android random but repeat 2 times

Tags: android, random

I have a little question concerning the usage of

[Android Resouce by ID / Change image onClick / no change of imageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41533112/android-resouce-by-id-change-image-onclick-no-change-of-imageview)

I have established my images picked randomly here, using:

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.d("MYAPP", "Like-Button clicked");

            /*imageViewMeasurement.setImageResource(R.drawable.p13);*/

            TypedArray images = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.images_primes);
            int chosenImageNumber = (int) (Math.random() * images.length());

            // setImageResource to the random chosenImageNumber
            imageViewMeasurement.setImageResource(images.getResourceId(chosenImageNumber, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
            images.recycle();

            // Confirmation if the random generator picked a Number from the array
            String chosenImageNumberTest = String.valueOf(chosenImageNumber);
            Log.d("MYAPP Choice Number", chosenImageNumberTest);
        }
```

This runs through an array of 40 images and will be repeated one time. So every image will be shown two times (?).

**That's the question:**
When I use a pool of 40 images randomly for 80 picks, do I get every image two times (draw with cover), or is every try a new random out of those 40 images (draw without replacement), so the reult could be number 1 for 4 times and number 38 for 0 times? Is there an other function that prevents to such a behaviour?

Best,
tigercode

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your code, you would NOT get every image twice, you would get some images multiple times and some images might not even come at all.

Don't use Random if you don't actually want Random. By the laws of probability you'd only have a chance of getting the same image twice, not a certainty.

Answer (score 1):

<s>You could use a boolean array to keep track of which numbers have already been used (if index n is true this means the number has already been taken e.g.).</s>

Edit: The comment below from vims liu is right. It's much more efficient run time wise to define a list of indexes and shuffle the list.

So better use the following solutions, even if it won't make a big differences considering your numbers are quite small.

```
 List<Integer> indexes = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10); //...
 Collections.shuffle(indexes);
```

You can then iterate through the indexes list and use the current number as current index.

Comment: this code might slow down (might hang a little while) if there is too many  numbers taken (for ex: 1 - 10 is taken, only 11 left, it is possible for the random generator to generate 1 - 10 multiple times before it can possibly generate 11), the best is put a list of items to get randomly and if that item is generated, remove it from list reinit the random seed to take account the new list size to avoid index out of range exception

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering late, and sorry for a beginner question, I'm new to android developing.

I changed my code (and write my comment what I understood it does:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)

        Log.d("MYAPP", "Like-Button clicked");

        // 1. Get the array of images in the images_primes XML-List AS int (number of every image in array)
        TypedArray images = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.images_primes);

        // 2. Takes an array-list and shuffles it
        List<Integer> indexes = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10); //...
        Collections.shuffle(indexes);

        // Great, it shuffles! ;-)
        Log.d("MYAPP", indexes);

        // 3. takes the number from the shuffled image list
        int chosenImageNumber = (int) (indexes);


        // 2. Old code: picks a number out of the image array from 1. / commented out
        //int chosenImageNumber = (int) (Math.random() * images.length());

        // 4. setImageResource to the random chosenImageNumber
        imageViewMeasurement.setImageResource(images.getResourceId(chosenImageNumber, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        images.recycle();

        // Confirmation if the random generator picked a Number from the array
        String chosenImageNumberTest = String.valueOf(chosenImageNumber);
        Log.d("MYAPP Choice Number", chosenImageNumberTest);
    }
```

Step 1: Open the list of images (as items), use it as array (1,2,3)

Step 2: Have a second number of arrays (possible to connect 1 and 2), SHUFFLE! :-)

Step 3: Here is my problem. If I got that right, I get a string-list from step 2, which numbers I can't use as Int (Error "Integer to int" won't work) -> result should be a number (?)

Step 4: Number from 3 should be used to pick out an image from list / array from 1.

I think, there is a thinking error on my side.

Thanks for your help in advance,
tigercode